# Fetching data trough checkboxes in laravel problem

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to get data from two different tables using two separate queries in Laravel. But I want to display these two tables data with two different check boxes, for example if I want to see publications detail or education detail or both, please help what I should to do with my view.

My code is shown here:

Controller code is ExampleController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Auth;


class ExampleController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

         $result = DB::table('education')->get();
         $data = DB::table('publications')->get();

         return view('triel',compact('result','data'));
    }

}
```

My view file is trail.blade.php and its code is given.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container"><br>
    <h1>Irfan Khan Triel Page</h1>

    <div class="text text-success text-center">
        PHD Research
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                PHD Research Area
            </th>
            <th>University</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>

     @foreach($result as $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$value->research_area}}</td>

            <td>{{$value->univ}}</td>

            <td>{{$value->country}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
       </table>

        <div class="text text-success text-center">
       Publications Detail
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Title
            </th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Year</th>
        </tr>

     @foreach($data as $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$value->title}}</td>

            <td>{{$value->status}}</td>

            <td>{{$value->year}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach

    </table>

    @endsection
```

My route file is given here.

```
Route::get('triel','ExampleController@index');
```

Please modify my view to take these two results separately by checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways that can be done to achieve what you're trying. The example I am showing is using Jquery.

1. Add an Id to your tables e.g

   `<table class="table" id="publication-detail">
   <table class="table" id="research-detail">`
2. Add event `on click` listener to your checkboxes. When one of the checkboxes gets clicked, lets say publication, then hide your research-detail table. e.g.

   `$(".checkbox-publication").click(function(){
         $("#research-detail").css('display', 'none');
         $("#publication-detail").css('display', 'block');
       });`

And vice versa. If both of them clicked, display both tables.

If you want to use something more advanced and efficient try Ajax.

1. https://api.jquery.com/click/
2. https://api.jquery.com/css/
3. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/